# Modifying a Lib Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I would like to override a Lib Model in my Models and add a relation.
What is the best way to do it ?

Example of a model in rpush lib:

https://github.com/rpush/rpush/blob/f82cc6a25861612ce118b2661f5a47bceb7ebd86/lib/rpush/client/active_record/app.rb

```
module Rpush
  module Client
    module ActiveRecord
      class App < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'rpush_apps'

        if Rpush.attr_accessible_available?
          attr_accessible :name, :environment, :certificate, :password, :connections, :auth_key, :client_id, :client_secret
        end

        has_many :notifications, class_name: 'Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::Notification', dependent: :destroy

        validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:type, :environment] }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to add a has_many relation without editing the gem
So I thought creating a models/app.rb with this would be a start:

```
class Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::App
  has_many :rel_group_apps
  has_many :groups, :through => :rel_group_apps
end
```

I tried this but nothing changed. Maybe my models/app.rb is not called ?:

```
module Rpush
  module Client
    module ActiveRecord
      module App
        def self.included(includer)
          includer.class_eval do
            has_many :rel_group_apps
            has_many :groups, :through => :rel_group_apps
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How should I do it ? Is there a way to extend a lib model without removing the original behavior ?

Thanks !

EDIT

I Made it work but only by putting this code directly in config/initializers/rpush.rb
It wasn't working in models/app.rb

```
class Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::App
  has_many :rel_group_apps
  has_many :groups, :through => :rel_group_apps
end
```

If someone has a nicer idea, I'll take it !

Answer (score 0):

Extend the class with class << self

```
class Rpush::Client::ActiveRecord::App
  class << self
    [your methods here]
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working. It says: "NoMethodError: undefined method `groups'". If I put my relations directly in the gem class lib, it works. Any idea what's happening ? ^^